# Finding duplicate files with python

Tags: python, file, duplicates, directory, web-crawler

I'm trying to write a Python script that will crawl through a directory and find all files that are duplicates and report back the duplicates. What's the best was to solve this?

```
import os, sys

def crawlDirectories(directoryToCrawl):
    crawledDirectory = [os.path.join(path, subname) for path, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directoryToCrawl) for subname in dirnames + filenames]
    return crawledDirectory

#print 'Files crawled',crawlDirectories(sys.argv[1])

directoriesWithSize = {}
def getByteSize(crawledDirectory):
    for eachFile in crawledDirectory:
        size = os.path.getsize(eachFile)
        directoriesWithSize[eachFile] = size
    return directoriesWithSize

getByteSize(crawlDirectories(sys.argv[1]))

#print directoriesWithSize.values()

duplicateItems = {}

def compareSizes(dictionaryDirectoryWithSizes):
    for key,value in dictionaryDirectoryWithSizes.items():
        if directoriesWithSize.values().count(value) > 1:
            duplicateItems[key] = value

compareSizes(directoriesWithSize)

#print directoriesWithSize.values().count(27085)

compareSizes(directoriesWithSize)

print duplicateItems
```

Why does this throw back this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    getByteSize(crawlDirectories(sys.argv[1]))
  File "main.py", line 12, in getByteSize
    size = os.path.getsize(eachFile)
  File     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 49, in getsize
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:        '../Library/Containers/com.apple.ImageKit.RecentPictureService/Data/Documents/iChats'
```

Comment: it worked without errors when run as >>python filename.py folderNameInHome

Comment: It seems to be related to symlinks. Any way around not crawling those?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your `crawledDirectory` function is too complicated:

```
def crawlDirectories(directoryToCrawl):
    output = []
    for path, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directoryToCrawl):
        for fname in filenames:
            output.append(os.path.join(path,fname))
    return output
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to try:

```
def crawlDirectories(directoryToCrawl):
    crawledDirectory = [os.path.realpath(os.path.join(p, f)) 
                                         for (p, d, f) in os.walk(directoryToCrawl)]
return crawledDirectory
```

That is, use a canonical path instead of relative paths in your crawl.